# Remove [ from a list in python when passing the list values to a a sample JSON request body

Tags: python

I have a quick question. I have a list in Python with the values.

```
service_list = [ AX100 , BX200 , CX300 ]
```

Now I am trying to pass this list to a sample JSON body where I can get a SNOW ticket opened so this is the Sample JSON data:

```
'u_template': 'CONFIG FILE', 
'approval': 'Request for Approval', 
'u_uuid': 'a13b8180-6400-11e8-a39e-005046a6000d',
 'short_description': 'short_description_ie ', 
'start_date': '2018-06-11 05:00:55',
 'end_date': '2018-06-12 05:00:55',
 'work_start': '2018-06-11 05:00:55', 
'work_end': '2018-06-12 05:00:55',
 'u_creating_group': 'sdo',
'u_affected_ci': service_list
}
```

But for the key `u_affected_ci` it is expecting the value to be only `AX100 , BX200 , CX300` and not `[ AX100 , BX200 , CX300 ]`, so please suggest me ideas how to remove the `[` in front and `]` at the back of the list add " " to cover the entire value and then pass to JSON body.

Comment: Be careful. Your terminology is incorrect. The `[` and `]` you mention **do not exist**. They represent a `list` object, and are used by Python as a visual aid to indicate a `list`. It *appears* you want to convert the items of a list to a string; use `str.join` for this.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the list with a `,`-delimited string.

```py
d = {
    ...,
    'u_affected_ci': ','.join(service_list)
}

data = json.dumps(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the JSON requires a **string** rather than a list. Instead of thinking of this as removing the `[]` from the list (which represents an array in JSON), you need to figure out how to convert your list into a string with the correct format. In particular, the string must be comma delimited. Thankfully we have the `join()` method on strings. It works like this:

```
> service_list = [ 'AX100' , 'BX200' , 'CX300' ]
> ','.join(service_list) 
=> 'AX100,BX200,CX300'
```

If you store the result in a variable, you can use that variable in the dictionary that you will serialize to JSON:

```
service_string = ','.join(service_list)
```